# After taking measurement of a particle in superposition states does it collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

I have this question:

A particle is trapped inside an infinite square well of width L, this particle is in a superposition state n=1 and n=3 such that :

$\psi(x)=\sqrt{2/5}\psi_1(x)+\sqrt{3/5}\psi_3(x)$

At time $t_1$ the probability density looks like the following this:

[image]

Then, a short time later, at $t_2$, the probability density looks like the following:
[image]

What is shape of the probability current, j(x)?

---

I was wondering if the following statement is correct:

When we measure a particle in a superposition state, it collapses to one of the above state, so the second graph the probability density of one of collapsed state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering the following as your doubt.

> When we measure a particle in a superposition state, it collapses to one of the above states, so the second graph the probability density of one of the collapsed states.

The given wavefunction $\psi(x)$ is a superposition of stationary states ($\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$). The particle can be in either of them with certain probability. So your first statement is correct.

---

This not specified whether or not you have done a measurement or not. So the fact that the second one is density of collapsed state can not be made. The state may evolve as time passes.

---

How the state evolve? For stationary states, We know that
$$i\hbar|\dot{\Psi}(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\Psi(t)\rangle=E|\Psi(t)\rangle$$
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle=\exp\left(-\frac{i Et}{\hbar}\right)|\Psi(0)\rangle$$
Right the following on position basis
$$\psi(x,t)=\exp\left(-\frac{i Et}{\hbar}\right)\psi(x,0)$$